# Button that only gets activated once the form is filled in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I want to create a xamarin.forms application that will be used for surveying. The user would be presented by multiple pages and he would be directed to the next pages only after they are done filling the fields mentioned in the present page.

Answer (score 1):

bind the Button's IsEnabled (or IsVisible) property to a bool property in your ViewModel IsPageComplete.  Every time a field is completed on the page test to see if all the required fields are complete, and if they are then update the IsPageComplete property.